# XmlSerializer loads “ in file as &quote; during deserialization - when XML contains Hebrew

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, deserialization, xmlserializer

Here is my xml:

```
<Product>
<ItemCode>123456</ItemCode>
<ItemName>תמצית מרווה משולשת  SP 1:2 - מ"ל 100</ItemName>
<FrgnName>Salvia fruitcosa</FrgnName>
</Product>
```

The `ItemName` includes `"` character. After deserialization this character is replaced by `&quot;`.
Here is my code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductXmlWrapper));
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {

     var product = (ProductXmlWrapper)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

     if (product != null)
     {
       SaveDataToDb(product.BO.Product);
     }
  }
```

So what should I change? Does it depend on the encoding?

Comment: @user2864740 this issue happens only with Hebrew text

Comment: @MichaelKostiuchenko What encoding are you using in the the xml header? Your sample deserializes as `\"` for me not `&quot;`.

Comment: the double quote is special character in xml and Net library automatically replaces the character.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Actually, escaping `"` as `&quot;` is necessary only in attribute values (and then only when `"` is used as the delimiter; but many serializers are a bit lazy and apply the same rules for attributes and text nodes - and the output is perfectly correct and should be acceptable to any properly-written XML application.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, whilst a preview of the product's `ItemName` property will include `&quot;` or `\"` as special characters within a string, this shouldn't effect the usage of that property.

I tested with the following and had exactly the content of the XML file printed to console:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            string file = @"Input.xml";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductXmlWrapper));
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var product = (ProductXmlWrapper)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
                Console.WriteLine(product.ItemName);
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Product")]
    public class ProductXmlWrapper
    {    
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string FrgnName { get; set; }
    }
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Product>
  <ItemCode>123456</ItemCode>
  <ItemName>תמצית מרווה משולשת  SP 1:2 - מ"ל 100</ItemName>
  <FrgnName>Salvia fruitcosa</FrgnName>
</Product>
```

Of course my PC isn't setup to support Hebrew (?) characters, but the `"` is output as per the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlReader instead using streams and use "utf-8" for encoding:

```
string file = @"Input.xml";     
using (var xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(file))
                {
                    var product = (ProductXmlWrapper)serializer.Deserialize(xmlreader,"utf-8");
                    Console.WriteLine(product.ItemName);
                }
```

Also add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` at top of the xml file.

Comment: This would require a very different declaration of the serializer since as is, it cannot support the encoding argument. See: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer_Deserialize_System_Xml_XmlReader_System_String_ )